# openssl self-signed certificate verify failed

Tags: ssl, openssl

Background: I create a self-made certificate and use the private key to sign some text.And then, use the self made certificate verify the signature.But I cannot verify successful.Here is my process.

```
# create Rsa public/private key
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048

# generate the certificate
openssl req -x509 -days 3650 -key private.key -out ca.csr

# generate text message
echo 'hello' > text

# sign text
openssl smime -sign -inkey private.key -signer ca.csr -in text -outform PEM -out signature

# verify signature
openssl smime -verify -noverify -content text -certfile ca.csr -inform PEM -in signature -signer ca.csr

hello

Verification failure
139927005472576:error:21071065:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_signatureVerify:digest failure:crypto/pkcs7/pk7_doit.c:1011:
139927005472576:error:21075069:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:signature failure:crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c:353:
```

what's wrong with my verification process.

In addition, if verify without -noverify option, which is in line with expectations

```
# verify signature
openssl smime -verify -content text -certfile ca.csr -inform PEM -in signature -signer ca.csr

Verification failure
139636965443472:error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:pk7_smime.c:336:Verify error:self signed certificate
```

Comment: **Should work**, and does for me **unless** the contents of `text` are changed (even one bit) in between, in which case I reproduce the error exactly (except threadid of course). PS: .csr is usually used for a certificate request aka CSR, and using it for a certificate will confuse people, but the software doesn't care. But this is not programming or development and is out of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I found whatever I sign the text, I could not verify successfully. Is there any example to show me the way to sign the text with openssl smime tools?

Comment: I just realized something -- from the comment format you are on Unix? Even for CMS/PKCS7 (which `smime -in|outform pem|der` do) OpenSSL applies the SMIME data rules, which by default forces line terminators to CRLF not LF as Unix uses. To skip this, add `-binary` to the `-sign` command; I don't _think_ you need it on `-verify` but if necessary try it. Alternatively, if suitable for your purpose(s), use data that has (all) CRLF terminators (that's what my working test did), or none.

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!!!! I love you so much! I add a -binary option when I sign the text. Incredible also powerful suggestions.